# Dynamic custom class on a UIView (in UICollection)

Tags: swift, swift3, xcode8

I have been searching for hours...maybe I am misunderstanding something simple...

I have a `UIView` in the cell of a `UICollection`. I would like to attach/add/change the custom class of the `UIView` from my view controller.

Something similar to...

```
cell.uiviewinstance = newclass()
```

I am trying to use a UIview as a container for an image in a cell of UIcollection. Then have some logic in my viewcontroller that adds a paintcode/stylekit class to the UIview.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that does not make any sense. You are just changing *one* reference, the "old" view is still present as a subview. You would have to remove the old view from its superview, add the new view and change the reference. But that will probably get you into trouble in regards to auto layout and more importantly it will probably mess cell dequeuing up badly

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? This these like the wrong way to do it.

Comment: @philipheinser I am trying to use a UIview as a container for an image in a cell of UIcollection. Then have some logic in my viewcontroller that adds a paintcode/stylekit class to the UIview. Does that make sense?

Comment: you should create some condition inside `cellForRow` and `reloadData` each time you would like to change your `UIView`, it would work, not sure this solution it the best